# Call Winforms Form Constructor Dynamically C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, constructor

I have two BaseForms: BaseFormListView and BaseFormDetailView which are providing pagination and search besides other details which should be available in forms which are derived by those.
The following derived forms implement specific behavior/fields necessary for CRUD-Actions on a country:

`public partial class frmCountry : BaseFormListView`

`public partial class frmCountryDetailView : BaseFormDetailView`

While further abstracting I came to a point where I do not know how to archive what I want.
Somewhere in my implementation I need to be concret and want to dynamically call a constructor like this:

`Form oReadWindow = new DetailForm(FormModus.READ, ulID);
oReadWindow.ShowDialog(this);`

This should happen in BaseFormListView when an entry of the List is clicked and I need to make decision based on FormModus if the user is requesting Create, Read, Update or Delete of the choosen recordset based in its ID (ulID).

So instead of "new DetailForm(FormModus.READ, ulID);" I need to call a constructor of any derived DetailView, be it frmCountry (like in the example) or frmArea or frmUser or whatever DetailForm is needed for this specific context.

I tried this
`var objectHandle = Activator.CreateInstance("MyApp", Form, new object[] { FormModus.READ, ulID });`
but compiler told me that type Form is not allowed in this context.

How should I solve this?

Thanks,
Steffi

Edit:
Here are more details for a better understanding.

Actually this is what I have:
`var objectHandle = Activator.CreateInstance("MyApp", DetailFormName, new object[] { FormModus.READ, ulID });`
`Form oReadFenster = (Form)objectHandle.Unwrap();`

When I do not use the first parameter in CreateInstance, I get the error "cannot convert from String to Type Form"

This is the Definition of DetailFormName:
`protected String DetailFormName { get; set; }  // in BaseFormListView`

The initialization value is provided this way:
`base.DetailFormName = "frmCountryDetailView";  // in the constructor of frmCountryDetailView`
which itsself is located in: public partial class frmCountry : BaseFormListView

The idea is to set base.DetailFormName different in each DetailForm (i.e. frmUser) which will be further derived from BaseFormListView which itsself is providing a paginated DGV and a configurable search and other thing for every XYListView which is derived from it.

Still, I get:
`System.TypeLoadException: 'Der Typ "frmCountryDetailView" in der Assembly "MyApp, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" konnte nicht geladen werden.'`

Comment: Have you inspected the documentation for `CreateInstance` and compared it to what you're actually passing? I see no overload with the signature you are trying to use.

Comment: changed it to 
`var objectHandle = Activator.CreateInstance("MyApp", frmCountryDetailView, new object[] { FormModus.READ, ulID });`
With that I get a System.TypeLoadException (the type of frmCountryDetailView in Assembly MyApp could not be loaded).

Comment: Try it without the first parameter, if all this is in the same assembly the a `assemblyName` parameter is not needed. But what you're doing there is the same as using new... you need to dynamically change the form type as well.

Comment: You are right, I edited my initial post to give a better understanding of what I have right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think CreateInstance is not needed. Invoke your frmCountryDetailView as its own specialized instance, like:

```
frmCountryDetailView oReadWindow = new frmCountryDetailView(ulID);
oReadWindow.ShowDialog(this);
```

and modify the constructor of frmCountryDetailView like:

```
public frmCountryDetailView(int uID) : base(FormModus.READ, ulID)
{
  InitializeComponent(); 
  // etc
}
```

Comment: If I do it the way you suggested, I won't be able to generalize BaseFormListView since I will have to call the constructor of frmCountryDetailView and the other ...DetailView-Constructors explicitly which I do not want to.

Comment: Hi Stefani, if you want to pop up a specific form, you will have to create it, so you will need to know the type  ! However, the instance you create does not need to be of type frmCountryDetailView. So you CAN write: BaseFormListView instance = new frmCountryDetailView(ulID) ..that works without a cast, because frmCountryDetailView derives from its base class.

Comment: I know but I want to implement a generic solution.